# Using AdControl to display ads in a WPF application packaged for UWP

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, desktop-bridge

I (appear to) have successfully created a UWP package for my WPF application using the following guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

Now I would like to take advantage of the AdControl class to display banner ads in my project, as detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net

Is this possible? I don't see the "Universal Windows" section under References for my WPF project, which I can guess is because it’s not an original Universal Windows project. I do see it under References for the UWP package wrapper project I created using the guide above, but that doesn't help me show ads in the WPF project.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add Universal Windows reference and use the API in your project as described [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/#TQdxTuypzITO7wQI.97) but you cannot use AdControl since XAML/UI in WPF is not the same as XAML in UWP and the AdControl is a UWP XAML control:

> As mentioned above, there are exceptions to the rule that Windows 10
>   APIs are accessible from PC software. The first big exception concerns
>   XAML UI APIs. The XAML framework in UWP is different from the one in
>   WPF and you really don’t want to be mixing them up, anyways.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. Looks like I'll need to find another avenue to display ads within my application.